# Insufficient permissions. Missing ReadPackages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm using Azure Pipelines to build, test and push my applications to the artifacts feed. Except the push step always errors with `error: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User '629355b9-***' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'. ).`

And a warning `User '629355b9-***' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'.`

Now, from several tutorials and video's I added `{project name} Build Service ({organisation name})` and `[{organisation name}]\Project Collection Builder Service Accounts` both with `Contributor`-role. Since it's about "reading" I've changed the views permissions (local) as well to `All feeds and people in organisations associated with my Azure Active Directory` (Really something I don't like). But to no luck.

The interesting part here is that the user id of the error differs from the user id of `{project name} Build Service ({organisation name})` which start with `0b7489ef-***`.

The push step:

```yaml
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: dotnet push
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '0b7489ef-***/541e117c-***'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add user to Azure Devops Artefacts. Please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops).

To find username, you may find this snippet useful:

```
 az devops invoke --area graph --resource users --api-version 5.1-preview -o json | jq -r '.value[] | select(.originId == "629355b9-***") | .displayName'
```

it uses Azure Devops CLI and `jq` tools to read list of available users and then filters out the required user's display name by its id.

Comment: `--organization` is a required parameter. But this fixed it. I ~read~ scanned the article multiple, but I guess I did it wrong. Thank you!

Comment: I just used the first part and found the guid: `az devops invoke --area graph --resource users --api-version 5.1-preview -o json`